# Is a "bradder" the same thing as a "brad nailer"?

Tags: power-tools, tools, tool-identification, nailing

It's a dumb thing for work, I just need to know if "bradder" is short-hand for "brad nailer."

"Bradder" is coming from this product at Home Depot: [F21P GN-31A (CT) Bradder](https://www.homedepot.com/p/FASCO-F21P-GN-31A-CT-Bradder-11132F/205179850?keyword=205179850&semanticToken=20030+++%3E++++st%3A%7B205179850%7D%3Ast++cn%3A%7B4%3A0%7D++205179850+%7Bproductkey%7D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Those hip talking advertising people.

Comment: It's what Home Depot is calling them now apparently